# jwplayer - QoE - get values liked described

Tags: jwplayer

on this page:
https://www.jwplayer.com/products/jwplayer/video-analytics/

QUALITY OF EXPERIENCE API
Use the JW Player QoE API to measure the performance of your videos. With events for visual quality, startup time, and amount of time spent buffering you are given the data needed to make the best decisions regarding your video deployments.

how to get 
- visual quality
- amount of time spent buffering

Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the Quality API calls available at https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#quality

You can also use `.on('firstFrame')` to get `loadTime` (The amount of time (In milliseconds) it takes for the player to transition from a play attempt to a firstFrame event)